# Remove Words with less than Certain Character Lengths plus Noise Reduction before Tokenization

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, tm, stop-words

I have the following data frame

```
report <- data.frame(Text = c("unit 1 crosses the street", 
       "driver 2 was speeding and saw driver# 1", 
        "year 2019 was the year before the pandemic",
        "hey saw       hei hei in        the    wood",
        "hello: my kityy! you are the best"), id = 1:5)
report 
                                         Text id
1                   unit 1 crosses the street  1
2     driver 2 was speeding and saw driver# 1  2
3  year 2019 was the year before the pandemic  3
4 hey saw       hei hei in        the    wood  4
5           hello: my kityy! you are the best  5
```

From a previous coding help, we can remove stop words using the following code.

```
report$Text <- gsub(paste0('\\b',tm::stopwords("english"), '\\b', 
                          collapse = '|'), '', report$Text)
report
                                    Text id
1                 unit 1 crosses  street  1
2      driver 2  speeding  saw driver# 1  2
3            year 2019   year   pandemic  3
4 hey saw       hei hei             wood  4
5                 hello:  kityy!    best  5
```

I want to remove words less than certain character length (for example, want to remove words less than 4 characters such as `hei` and `hey`). Plus need to remove manual stop words (for example, `saw` and `kitty`) and common noises (whitespaces, numbers, and punctuations) before tokenization. The final outcome would be:

```
                                    Text id
1                   unit crosses  street  1
2                driver speeding  driver  2
3                     year year pandemic  3
4                                   wood  4
5                             hello best  5
```

A similar question regarding noise and manual stop words is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71971099/remove-numbers-punctuations-white-spaces-before-tokenization/71971183).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the previous code, if we start with removal of words that have `nchar` less than or equal to 3 (with `gsubfn`) it should work

```
trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b(", paste(union(c("saw", "kityy"), 
   tm::stopwords("english")), collapse="|"), ")\\b"), "", 
     gsub("[[:punct:]0-9]+", "",gsubfn("\\w+", function(x) 
     if(nchar(x) > 3) x else '', report$Text))))))
```

-output

```
[1] "unit crosses street"    "driver speeding driver" 
[3] "year year pandemic"     "wood"                   "hello best"
```